# Export data with bcp in SQL Server produces nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, export, bcp

I am  exporting data in SQL Server 2005 with the following command but it produces nothing in SQL server 2008, no file is created although the query is executed succesfully:

```
execute xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM MYDB.dbo.MYTABLE" queryout d:\file.csv -c -t; -S(local) -T'
```

What is wrong with my command?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to execute the command. Solution:
I installed more than one sql server versions. And the management studio cannot find the bcp.exe because in the enviroment path, there are more than one paths for the bcp.exe. You can check this by executing bcp.exe from command prompt and it will say sqlncli.dll was not found.
So you have to put the exact path of bcp.exe to the enviroment path (or in front of other paths). So that windows can use it. Then dont forget to restart the sql server in order to change in paths takes effect. In conclusion, my command is not wrong but the path of bcp.exe is wrong.